# Reference about history of characteristic classes

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

I'm looking for a good reference about  history of characteristic classes. For example, I would like to know how Chern define the Chern class at first in history, or who rewrote the characteristic classes in language of cohomology theory the first-ever. Thank you for your helping!

Comment: Is there any reason [Chern's _Annals_ paper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0015793), and/or bibliographic references in Milnor, don't adequately answer your question? :)

Comment: I'm also interested, could you share what you've found?